# Not Getting Event Data for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up GA event tracking on a test site I have.  I use the asynch call in the page and then send events on click.  the code I use is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];

        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXX-1']);  // This is where my real Analytics Account number would be

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AdvertImpression', 'MEA','logged In']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AdvertImpression', 'AN Other Advert','not logged in']);


        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

        })();
```

I also have an onclick event.

```
 <A href="http://www.xxxyyy.com/ad/click/taHR"><IMG src="http://img.xxxyyy.com/banners/OPFME-20121211.jpg" width=468 height=60 border=0 alt="MEA"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AdvertClicked', 'MEA','Logged In'])")></A>
```

I see the site visits appear and my account says that events are being generated.  When I select "Unique Events" I even see quantities but I cannot see any of the specific category information in the drill down.

I have remove all filters on the account and have waited for 48 hrs.  Is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics records data by making tracking image requests. If you're loading a new page in the same window before the tracking request has completed, no data will be recorded. I've had good luck with a slight delay before following the link.

Try the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackLink(link, category, action, value) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, value ]);
    if (link.target == "_blank") return true;
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = link.href; }, 150)
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Add it the link as follows -- the `return` in the onlick is required.

```
<a href="http://www.xxxyyy.com/ad/click/taHR" onclick="return trackLink('AdvertClicked', 'MEA','Logged In')">...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tag.

If the links you're adding tracking to could be added in a new window (e.g. if they are adverts or external links), then you can fix this by simply adding `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tag to make the external link open in a new window.

This way you don't need to do any kind of delay (the original page keeps running and the javascript gets plenty time to complete) and you will always track your click - depending on network-speed/google load/various other things, 150 milliseconds may not be long enough to track the click resulting in fewer clicks.

Mostly, these types of clicks *should* be to external links anyway, otherwise you'd already have tracking in Google Analytics for these clicks since a new page would be loaded with your Analytics code on it.

```
<a href="http://www.xxxyyy.com/ad/click/taHR" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.xxxyyy.com/banners/OPFME-20121211.jpg" width=468 height=60 border=0 alt="MEA"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AdvertClicked', 'MEA','Logged In'])")></a>
```

If this still doesn't help, open your browser's javascript console - in Chrome hit CTRL+SHIFT+I then click the console tab - and check for any errors.

A problem I've seen elsewhere is _gaq is undefined which can happen if the Google Analytics script is not included properly on the page.